# Format the query result

Tags: java, regex, jakarta-ee

I have particular query which will retrieve results as

```
Row[values=[a/b/c/s, bell]]

Row[values=[e/g/i/r, bell]]
```

after the execution of below line in java.

```
System.out.println(dataSet.getRow());
```

I need to display results as

```
a/b/c/s bell

e/g/i/r bell
```

and

```
a/b/c/s

e/g/i/r
```

Is there any regex for that?

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<==\[)(([^,]+),\s+[^\]]+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture.See demo.If you want to remove `,` from first result use `replace` to remove `,` and replace by `empty string`.

https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/15